# Convert scientific exponential value to log and reverse jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, nouislider

I need to convert exponential values to log and back to exponential. Using it for [noUislider](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/). What i have tried,

Example A:

```
a = 5.45e-320
5.45e-320

b = Math.log(a)
-735.1316071514119

Math.exp(b)
5.45e-320
```

Example A is working fine for me but when i try this example

```
a = 2e-8
2e-8

b = Math.log(a)
-17.72753356339242

Math.exp(b)
2.0000000000000004e-8
```

Expected and needed Output: **2e-8**

I am curious to know **how this Math.log and Math.exp works**, I researched on many documents but didn't find my answer.

Please correct me if i am wrong here, Thanks.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken .You can find your answers there